# count vs length vs size in a collection

Tags: collections, naming-conventions, terminology, semantics

From using a number of programming languages and libraries I have noticed various terms used for the total number of elements in a collection.

The most common seem to be `length`, `count`, and `size`.

eg.

```
array.length
vector.size()
collection.count
```

Is there any preferred term to be used?
Does it depend on what type of collection it is? ie. mutable/immutable

Is there a preference for it being a property instead of a method?

Comment: And there is `List.Capacity` property as well in C#.

Comment: I hope new languages will avoid ambiguous terms.

Comment: What about languages that use more than one inconsistently?  I can never remember which to use (I'm pointing at Java and kotlin especially).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

`Length()` tends to refer to contiguous elements - a string has a length for example.

`Count()` tends to refer to the number of elements in a looser collection.

`Size()` tends to refer to the size of the collection, often this can be different from the length in cases like vectors (or strings), there may be 10 characters in a string, but storage is reserved for 20. It also may refer to number of elements - check source/documentation.

`Capacity()` - used to specifically refer to allocated space in collection and not number of valid elements in it. If type has both "capacity" and "size" defined then "size" usually refers to number of actual elements.

I think the main point is down to human language and idioms, the size of a string doesn't seem very obvious, whilst the length of a set is equally confusing even though they might be used to refer to the same thing (number of elements) in a collection of data.

Comment: So what's a "looser collection"? I'm not seeing the difference between size and count here.

Comment: @ben: size = available slots, count = actual elements. size == count when the collection is full.

Comment: @SnOrfus, that's still true, but I meant for collections that didn't have any meaningful contiguous elements, eg a map or a dictionary. You wouldn't say that a set had a length of 10 elements, there'd be a count of 10 elements in that.

Comment: Downvoting because `size()` refers to the number of elements in the vector, *not* its `capacity()`… at least in C++, which I think is the originator of `vector`s with `size`s.

Comment: @DaveAbrahams - I never said that was the case. Read it again. I said it "tends to refer", I never even tried to make a specific statement that applied equally to all permutations of all collection classes in all languages.

Comment: Completely unrelated yet interestingly, a "length" (or measure) of a mathematical set is definitely not the same as its "size" (or number of elements in the set). Example: the interval [0,1] has a "length" of 1 but has a "size" of [aleph_1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_1#Aleph-one).

Comment: @SnOrfus I think you've gone into the realm of "capacity" there. [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) (C++) for example uses "capacity" and "size" where you use "size" and "count", respectively. Actually, *everything* in `std::` uses "size" for the current element count, even `std::string` (which provides "size" for template compatibility and a completely identical "length" for... human convenience I guess).

Comment: So to be more Cocoa I should make `.numberOfElements()`? ;P

Comment: **In PowerShell, `Count` should always be used instead of `Length`** because even though `Count` and `Length` produce the same result for arrays, collection objects don't return the expected result for `Length`. For example, `([ordered]@{'a' = 0; 'bc' = 0;'def' = 0;}).Keys.Length` returns `1,2,3` and not `3`. This is because `Length` returns a list of `Length` properties for each key, which is the length of each string.

Answer (score 32):

FWIW (and that's vanishingly close to nothing), I prefer 'Count' because it seems to indicate that it's going to return the number of elements/items in the collection pretty unambiguously.

When faced with the terms 'Length' or 'Size' I'm often left wondering for a moment (or even being forced to re-read documentation) whether the damn thing is going to tell me how many elements are in the collection or how many bytes the collection is consuming. This is particularly true for collections that are intended to be contiguous like arrays or strings.

But no one who was responsible for the naming conventions used by the Java, BCL/.Net, or C/C++ standard frameworks/libraries bothered to ask me, so you're all stuck with whatever they came up with.

If only I were much smarter than I am and was named Bjarne, all of you might be spared the misery...

Of course, back in the real world, you should try to stick with whatever naming convention is used by the language/platform you're using (eg., `size()` in C++).  Not that this seems to help you with your `Array.Length` dilemma.

Comment: While Length and Size are nouns, Count is also a verb, thus it could be interpreted as counting at runtime (O(n)) vs lookup a value (O(1)).

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly how it's used in LINQ: [Enumerable.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count)

Comment: Funny enough, the D language uses `length` everywhere from the number of characters in a string, the number of key-value pairs in a hash-map to the number of elements in a parameter pack.

Answer (score 16):

The terms are somewhat interchangeably, though in some situations I would prefer one over another. Usually you can get the best usage if you think about **How would you describe the length/size/count of this element verbally to another person?**

`length()` implies that the element has a length. A string has a length. You say "a string is 20 characters long", right? So it has a length.

`size()` implies that the element has a size. E.g. a file has a size. You say "this file has a size of 2 MB", right? So it has a size.

That said, a string can also have a size, but I'd expect something else here. E.g. a UTF-16 string may have a length of 100 characters, but as every character is composed out of two byte, I'd expect size to be 200.

`count()` is very unusual. Objective-C uses count for the number of elements in an array. One might argue if an array has a length (as in Java), has a size (as in most other languages) or has a count. However, size might again be the size in byte (if the array items are 32 bit int, each item is 4 byte) and length... I wouldn't say "an array is 20 elements long", that sounds rather odd to me. I'd say "an array has 20 elements". I'm not sure if count expresses that very well, but I think count is here a short form for `elementCount()` and that again makes much more sense for an array than `length()` or `size()`.

If you create own objects/elements in a programming language, it's best to use whatever other similar elements use, since programmers are used to accessing the desired property using that term.

Comment: Following your string analogy a file must have a `length`, but different storages might use different `sizes` to store its data. Java also think so in _java.io.File#length()_, but it seems like the rest of the world disagrees.

Comment: @IvanBalashov I never used "length of file" in daily talk, for me a file has no length but a size and that's also what I wrote in my reply. Whenever we are talking of raw bytes we are talking of size IMHO and a file with no closer specific content is just a bunch of bytes. Length is usually not used for expressing byte count but to express a accumulation of elements stringed together (bytes are not elements to me, more the building blocks to form elements and they are also not "stringed together").

Answer (score 5):

Count I think is the most obvious term to use if you're looking for the number of items in a collection.  That should even be obvious to new programmers who haven't become particularly attached to a given language yet.

And it should be a property as that's what it is:  a description (aka property) of the collection.  A method would imply that it has to do something to the collection to get the number of items and that just seems unintuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm...I would not use size. Because this might be confused with size in bytes.
Length - could make some sense for arrays, as long as they are supposed to use consequent bytes of memory.
Though...length...in what?
Count is clear. How many elements. I would use count.

About property/method, I would use property to mark it's fast, and method to mark it's slow.

And, the most important - I would stick to the standards of the languages/libraries you are using.

Comment: So what about a DataBlock, just a bunch of bytes. Does it have a length or does it have a size?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @gbjbaanb's answer...

If "property" implies public access to the value, I would say that "method" is preferred simply to provide encapsulation and to hide the implementation.

You might change you mind about how to `count` elements or how you maintain that `count`.  If it is a property, you're stuck - if it is acessed via a method, you can change the underlying implementation without impacting users of the collection.

Comment: Why are you "stuck" if it is exposed as a property? Properties have an underlying implementation that can change just as easily without breaking the interface. In fact, most languages implement properties as compiler generated get/set methods anyway...you just can't call them directly.

Comment: Which "most languages" are you referring to? C, C++, Java (just to name a few) don't do this.  Ruby and Groovy I know do. Please note how I started the answer, too: "If 'property' implies ..."  Why stuck?  If the interface to the class changes, clients have to change (generally speaking)

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin** answer

from _Collections.kt

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.count(): Int {
    return size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Elixir there is actually a clear naming scheme associated with it across types in the language.

> When “counting” the number of elements in a data structure, Elixir
>   also abides by a simple rule: the function is named `size` if the
>   operation is in constant time (i.e. the value is pre-calculated) or
>   `length` if the operation is linear (i.e. calculating the length gets
>   slower as the input grows).

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is a little like asking whether "foreach" is better than "for each". It just depends on the language/framework.

Comment: And, what does it matter?  What changes?  Are we all going to write angry emails to the Java folks for picking two and being inconsistent?

Comment: That is my point. Why wonder which is better. It is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends on particular **language** that you are using and **classes**. For example in c# if you are using Array you have **Property** Length,  if you have something that inherits from IEnumerable you have extension **Method** Count(), but it is not fast. And if you inherited from ICollection you have **Property** Count.