# Differences between Array.Length and Array.Count()

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection)
>   [Array.Length vs Array.Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506963/array-length-vs-array-count)

I declared this array:

```
int[] misInts = new Int[someNumber];

/* make some happy operations with the elements in misInts */
```

So I can get the value of SomeNumber with:
misInts.Length or misInts.Count()

Arrays in C# inherit from IEnumerable. So if I have:

```
Func<int> misIntsF = Enumerable.Range(0, someNumber).Select(c=> /* make some happy operations that return Integers */);
```

I am told that if I make misIntsF.Count() I actually execute the code in the Lambda expression, get the results and count them. But the array misInts doesn't have a Lambda expressión.

Is misInts.Count() more memory consuming than misInts.Length? What are the differences between misInts.Count() and misInts.Length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506963/array-length-vs-array-count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Comment: @Kiyura your linked questions talk about terminology. This question asks about performance.

Comment: (Bob Ross) - "make some happy operations with the elements in misInts"

Comment: You're right Rotem, I'm concerned about memory comsumption and performance because this is part of a larger algorithm with loops inside loops inside loops everywhere.

Comment: @Rotem, this is why it's a comment and not an answer, and also why I didn't say "duplicate," it was only meant to be a pointer to information OP might not have seen yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`array.Count()` is actually a call to the `Enumerable.Count<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` extension method.

Since this method takes an `IEnumerable<T>` (as opposed to `ICollection<T>`, which has a `Count` property), it needs to loop through the entire sequence to figure out how big it is.

However, it actually checks whether the parameter implements `ICollection<T>` (which arrays do), and, if so, returns `Count` directly.
Therefore, calling `.Count()` on an array isn't much slower than `.Length`, although it will involve an extra typecast.

Comment: I came across this answer looking for the difference between `Count` and `Length` in PowerShell. **In PowerShell, `Count` should always be used instead of `Length`** because even though `Count` and `Length` produce the same result for arrays, collection objects don't return the expected result for `Length`. For example, `([ordered]@{'a' = 0; 'bc' = 0;'def' = 0;}).Keys.Length` returns `1,2,3` and not `3`. This is because `Length` returns a list of `Length` properties for each key, which is the length of each string.

Comment: @DaveF you should make your comment into an Answer, because you have the best answer here!  What you mention can definitely bite someone if they are not paying close attention.

Answer (score 11):

There is no great difference since [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) looks first if it's castable to  [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx).

MSDN:

> If the type of source implements ICollection, that implementation
>   is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method
>   determines the count.

Source:

```
ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
if (collection != null)
{
    return collection.Count;
}
```

otherwise it will enumerate the sequence to count it:

```
int num = 0;
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
```

(source: [**ILSpy**](http://ilspy.net/))

Comment: Please not: Although you quote ILSpy as your source, this actually is *not* just an implementation detail, it indeed is documented.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I've also linked MSDN, but since the source is quite readable in this case i have shown that instead. However, edited my answer to also quote msdn to make it clear.

Comment: I know that you linked it. I justed wanted to emphasise the fact that it is not an implementation detail as I just had this exact discussion a few days back with someone else. And the way your answer is structured it looks like you infered this info only from the source code and not from the documentation.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Edited my answer to make it more clear. But since Slaks has already answered it theoretically i just wanted to add something new instead of just quoting MSDN or repeat his answer in other words. Linq often appears magical for people, so it might help to see the code behind.