# Why does C# array not have Count property?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance, interface, ilist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection)

Really strange:

C# arrays such as the following

```
double[] test = new double[1];
```

support the Length property to get the size of the array. But arrays also implement an IList interface:

```
IList<double> list = test;
```

However, the IList interface provides also a Count property. How come the array ("test" in this case) doesn't?

**Edit**: Thanks to all of you who pointed out that it is in fact the ICollection interface (not IList) which provides the Count property, and also that this is due to explicit implementation of the interface.

Comment: ... vs **Capacity** vs **ItemCount** (like `ColumnCount` in `ListView` vs `Columns.Count`) vs **NumItems** (`NumIndices` in `EnvDTE`) vs **CountOfItems** (`CountOfLines` in `EnvDTE`) vs etc ... I just *love* the consistency in MS's frameworks. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply, they chose to call it `Length`, and implement `Count` via explicit interface implementation -something like:

```
int ICollection.Count { get { return Length; } }
```

Comment: +1 from me, but I'm guessing maybe they were looking for an answer to the "why" part?

Comment: @mehrdad - I wish I had my annotated spec on me :(

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to explicit interface implementations - had no idea that such things exist ;-)

Answer (score 9):

It was a design choice about Naming, not semantics.

Arrays have a **Length** property, as does the String.

**Length** signals immutable: You cannot Add to or Remove from an array.

Lists and other containers have a **Count** property that can usually change.

Oh, and if you call  `list.Append(1.1);` you will get a not supported exception.

Comment: Length by no means signals immutable; `MemoryStream` (actually, lots of stream implementations), `StringBuilder`, etc

Comment: @Marc: I didn't mean to imply a very strict rule. Streams are another domain, and I think StringBuilder.Length is a concession to String. I still think it loosely holds for containers.

Answer (score 5):

Types inheriting from `Array` [obtain implementations of `IList<T>` at run-time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) (how this is possible, don't ask me):

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the
>   `Array` class implements the
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`,
>   and
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`
>   generic interfaces. **The
>   implementations are provided to arrays
>   at run time**, and therefore are not
>   visible to the documentation build
>   tools. As a result, the generic
>   interfaces do not appear in the
>   declaration syntax for the `Array`
>   class, and there are no reference
>   topics for interface members that are
>   accessible only by casting an array to
>   the generic interface type (explicit
>   interface implementations). The key
>   thing to be aware of when you cast an
>   array to one of these interfaces is
>   that members which add, insert, or
>   remove elements throw
>   `NotSupportedException`.

In effect the `IList<T>` implementation acts like an [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), as [Marc explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769971/why-does-c-array-not-have-count-property/4769992#4769992) in his answer. This is why you can access certain members of `IList<T>` from the result of a cast but not from a variable typed as `T[]` specifically.

Comment: That last line was in essence already in the question.

Comment: @Henk: You're right; I meant to highlight the "explicit implementation" part; including the code example was superfluous and only distracted from that point. I removed it.

Answer (score 5):

The `Count` property is hidden using the explicit interface declaration style, for example like this in a class definition:

```
int IList.Count {
    get {
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```

You can access methods and properties hidden like this using a type cast, e.g.

```
((IList<double>) myArray).Count
```

Comment: IList doesn't actually define Count; ICollection does

Comment: @Marc: The way that interfaces inherit makes that rather moot.

Comment: @Henk - I'd need to check, but does it *compile* if you get it wrong? I didn't think so...

Comment: @Henk - tested: "Error 1 'IList.Count' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface" - so the compiler doesn't think it is a moot point.

Comment: @Marc: right. my mistake. I was thinking how Reflector sometimes shuffles if-members around.