# RunTimeBinderException when passing int[] to method having parameter type dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

Below code work perfectly fine unless I change `GetCount` parameter type from `ICollection` to `dynamic` - it throws `RuntimrBinderException` Why at runtime `Count` property is not available ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            var x = GetCount(list);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        private static int GetCount(ICollection array) /*changing array type to dynamic fails at runtime*/
        {
            return array.Count;
        }
```

Comment: Coz Array does not have Count property. Array has Length property. try with `array.Length` and `dynamic`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : code is working perfect when it is `ICollection`

Comment: Yes.. coz ICollection has Count property. When you use dynamic, Array does not get converted to ICollection, compiler will try to use the properties which are specific to the type which is passed. And Array does not have Count property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769971/why-does-c-sharp-array-not-have-count-property

Comment: Array implements ICollection.Count property via explicit interface implementation that's why Count property is not available directly on Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is because in arrays, although they implement `ICollection`, `Count` is implemented explicitly. Explicitly implemented members can only be invoked through the interface typed reference.

Consider the following:

```
interface IFoo 
{
    void Frob();
    void Blah();
} 

public class Foo: IFoo
{
     //implicit implementation
     public void Frob() { ... }

     //explicit implementation
     void IFoo.Blah() { ... }
}
```

And now:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Frob(); //legal
foo.Blah(); //illegal
var iFoo = foo as IFoo;
iFoo.Blah(); //legal
```

In your case, when the argument is typed `ICollection`, `Count` is a valid invocation, but when `dynamic` is used, the argument isn't implicitly converted to `ICollection`, it remains a `int[]` and `Count` is simply not invocable through that reference.