# System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my C# Project, I am getting this error that the definition for count does not contain `System.Array`

```
protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo[] fileInfo;
    string UpFolder = Server.MapPath("~/data/images/");
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(UpFolder);
    fileInfo = dir.GetFiles();
    // here i am getting error
    int TotalImages = fileInfo.Count();
    for (int count = 0; count < TotalImages; count++)
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.ImageUrl = "~/data/images/" + fileInfo[count].ToString();
        image.ID = count.ToString();
        DataListImage.Controls.Add(image);
    }
    DataListImage.DataSource = dir.GetFiles();
    DataListImage.DataBind();

    string UpFolder1 = Server.MapPath("~/data/thumbnails/");
    DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(UpFolder1);
    DataListthumbnails.DataSource = dir1.GetFiles();
    DataListthumbnails.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need `Count`, instead you can use `Length` with arrays to get the count.

You are getting the error since you are missing `using System.Linq;`

To get `TotalImages` you can use

```
int TotalImages = fileInfo.Length;
```

Comment: i was using System.Linq already but why cant i use count here??? since there are some difference between count and length As i am resizing the image on the behalf of count images.. as much as images size it will be Optimized accordingly

Comment: @SiddiqBaig, `Count` would return total number of elements in an your array, same as lenght, It doesn't has anything to do with Image Size. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection for Length Vs Count.

Answer (score 6):

While `Count()` isn't *"needed"* since the type is an Array, the error is a result of not "using" the correct namespaces.

[`Enumerable.Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a LINQ *extension* method in the `System.Linq` namespace. As such, it can be made available with the following:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Since arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`, then they can utilize any such methods when they are made available.

Comment: Cool, I love when that happens :)