# Unreachable Code Detected C#

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, control-structure, unreachable-code

Im trying to Post an unlimited number of likes but looping the cookies and proxies based on the how many cookies are stored in the array. Apparently i++ is unreachable code. What is the reason for that?

```
public void PostLikes()
{
   PostLike postLike = new PostLike();
   for (int i =0;i<this.cookies.ToArray().Length;i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; ; j++)
      {
         postLike.PostLike(this.cookies[i], this.importedProxies[i], this.proxyUsernameTextbox, this.proxyPasswordTextbox, this.postsIds[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What type is `cookies`?

Comment: Why would you tag this as C++ and Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And don't do this

```
for (int i =0;i<this.cookies.ToArray().Length;i++)
```

because

```
this.cookies.toArray().Length
```

its evaluating in every iteration of the for loop, you are making 'this.cookies' to array every time so just you get its length? :) You are increasing the complexity of the method

Comment: well it is a list. How do I get the Length of a list?

Comment: @user2880751 see the [`Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) And if you're curious why lists has `.Count` while arrays have `.Length`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Comment: @user2880751 Use `list.Count`. Store it in a variable and reference that variable in the loop though so it's only read once.

Comment: @DavidArno AFAIK the optimizer is smart enough to not need an extra variable. list.Count is referenced only once if there is no change to list in the loop.

Answer (score 7):

The *real* problem is that:

```
for (int j = 0; ; j++)
```

Produces an infinite loop, assuming you don't have any other control statements inside (e.g. `break`, `return`, `goto`, `throw`)

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < this.postsIds.Length; j++)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; ; j++)
```

This is a dead loop, so i++ won't be reached