# how to print all words the end with ed?

Tags: javascript

This program prints all words in the textarea if there is ed.
I need to print all words in the textarea that end with ed.

```js
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function testString()
{
var myForm = document.getElementById( "myForm" );
var s = myForm.input.value;
if ( s.substr( s.length - 2, 2 ) == "ed" )
myForm.output.value += s + "\n";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "myForm" >
<textarea name = "input" rows = "10" cols = "55"></textarea><br />
<input type = "button" value = "Submit" onclick = "testString()" /><br />
<textarea name = "output" rows = "10" cols = "55"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MSDN is very good starting point to investigate problems. I.e. searching for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Console.ReadLine should give you some explanation about what `ReadLine` actually doing and it hopefully will help to understand your code... Debugging is second steps - hopefully when you finish you are close to solution, or at least can update question to make it more concrete.

Comment: Stop marking him down and give the guy a chance to clarify the question.

Comment: Please improve the question: If you have multiple different questions, think of starting a new topic for each. What is your programming the problem? What are you trying to achieve? Why couldn't you achieve it so far? What did you try?

Comment: The question is written above how  to improve the question ? @Rias

Comment: I don't understand the context of your questions. It looks like three (or more) questions to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The difference between the arrays:**

The difference between `double[] array = new double[a.Count - 2];` and `double[] array = new double[a.Count];` is the length of the array you are declaring. When you are passing a integer value into the constructor of your new array that is the length your array will be initialized with.

**Notes on array declaration and length:**

This length cannot be changed after declaration and you must create a new array and copy elements to the new collection.

**Value vs reference comparison:**

As for your comparisons throughout your method, there is two primary forms of comparison, comparison by value and comparison by reference. Comparison by value returns true if the value of two objects (int, string, etc.) are the same. Comparison by reference returns true if two variables point to the same place in memory. You should be using the `.Equals()` method instead of "==", this will assure you are comparing by value and not by reference.

**Further Notes:**

Also something to note that you will have to go out and research for yourself is length and count are not the same. The difference is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection).

Comment: If this answered your question please make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: how to make it accepted @CalebB

Comment: Click on the check make under the number at the top left of the answer. The check should turn green.

Comment: do u know why the if () break is not working ?

Comment: As I said in my answer it's most likely a comparison of value vs reference issue. Try using the .Equals method and see if it still gives you issues. Other than that place a break point and see what the value of Read is when it is compared to whatever.

Comment: it is giving me error use of unassigned local variable@CalebB sorry for asking a lot of question

Comment: That's fine. Try initializing Read as `string Read = null` instead of placing it unintialized.