# Why do JavaScript Sets/Maps use `size` instead of `length`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

While looking over new changes to JavaScript I noticed that [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) use `.size` instead of `.length` like arrays would.

This seems like a pointless diversion from what's normal with arrays - just one more thing to remember.

Was there a good design reason for this?

Comment: My guess is that sets and maps are not really considered one-dimensional vectors *(having a "length")* of items, like arrays are. Would you consider it bad to also name the size of a heap or a stack something other than `length`?

Comment: This is a good question that will answer yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Comment: In the case of Set at least, if you look at the spec, the main difference as opposed to Array's length is that size is recalculated each time you call it. Now I'm not sure that's the main reason for naming it differently, and I actually doubt it.

Comment: @bug-a-lot Not necessarily - further up the spec it also says _"The data structures used in this Set objects specification is only intended to describe the required observable semantics of Set objects. It is not intended to be a viable implementation model."_ the size could be cached when things are added etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yep, there's no surprise there. As I was writing the answer I was actually thinking that no one in their right mind would actually implement it the way it's being exemplified in the spec.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a lot of discussion in the esdiscuss thread ["Set length property"](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/set-length-property). This was a hotly debated issue, so it's not surprising that you do not necessarily agree with the resolution.

There is a tremendous amount of arguing about this in esdiscuss. Ultimately, the argument that prevailed (as evidenced by the fact that ES2015's Sets have `size` and not `length`) was summarized in [a post by David Bruant](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nov-17-meeting-notes#content-8):

> ...for me 'length' refers to a measurement with something like a ruler. You start at 0 and see up to where it goes. This is very accurate for an array which is an indexed set (starting at 0 and growing) and for arrays as considered in C (continuous sequence of bytes) which ECMAScript arrays seem inspired of. This is probably less relevant for unordered collections such as sets which I'd tend to consider as a messy bag.

And further discussed in [a post by Dean Landolt](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nov-17-meeting-notes#content-12):

> Just wanted to jump in and say non-writable `length` is consistent with String behavior as well, but David makes a good point about `length` implying metric topology. David's suggestion of `count` is nice. ISTM what we're talking about is `cardinality`, but no need to get too silly w/ precision. Though `size` is just fine with me, and has plenty of prior art.

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer to the question really.  I wonder if anyone has thought about doing a project that annotates the specification with links to where things were discussed... hmm...

Comment: it is unfortunate that using size loses polymorph property with existing arrays. Using length would be still semantically appropriate. Cmon guys, no one thinks about "rulers" when instantiating lists in memory, it doesn't matter if the property is size, count or length as long as it is always the same. Now when refactoring code we have to always check for size vs length, etc. Annoying

Answer (score 1):

While apsillers' Jan 27, 2016 answer adds great links, a code example is missing. The `size` of a set is a read-only getter while that's not the case for arrays which allow modifying the `length` to truncate the array.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.length = 2
console.log("modified length array", arr) // [1, 2]

let mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4])
mySet.length = 2
mySet.size = 2
console.log("modified length set", [...mySet]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]

let str = "1234"
str.length = 2
console.log("modified length string", str) // "1234"
```

Comment: I've been looking for best practices on truncating a Map, since Maps are often a very preferable structure to Arrays when it comes to something with a set insertion order baked in of items and a lookup, both at once. But as far as I can tell, the only way to truncate a map is to iterate over it, which seems very slow in comparison to setting and array's length (which then tosses out GCs everything no longer indexed). But I can see why that might just be how it is/has to be.