# Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 6

Tags: c#, arrays

i have a problem regarding my code. I have tried searching on it, but it only confused me more.

I want to split an array(called `Array` for simplicity)  of size 6 in half. one of the halves will move to another array, called `Split1`

But it gives me an error when trying to move the numbers using a for loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,,,,,] Array = new int[7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1];
            int[] Split1 = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                Split1[i] = Array[i]; //This is where i get my error
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you could point me to the right direction, I would be grateful

Comment: You must read about Arrays in c# language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
int[,,,,,] Array = new int[7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1];
```

is not an array with 6 elements, this is a 6-dimentional array.

You should define your one dimensional array like this:

```
int[] Array = new int[] {7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1};
```

Additionally, your loop condition is incorrect, you should use `<` to check upper bound instead of `<=`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length / 2; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I haven't programmed in C# for a while, so I was a bit rusty on the Array side

Answer (score 3):

[Initialize your array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as

```
int[] Array = new int[6]{7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1};
```

What you did before was attempt to create array with 6 dimensions and address one of its cell.

As others pointed out, in loop you want to count from 0 to 2, therefore change `<=` for `<`.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong index with loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length / 2; i++)
{
    Split1[i] = Array[i]; //This is where i get my error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you declare the Array is incorrect, see the following code.

```
int[] Array = new int[] {7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1}; // initialization will set the size automatically
int[] Split1 = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Split1[i] = Array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) You can initialize 1D arrays in [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes) :

```
        string[] array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
        string[] array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
        string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
```

In your case :

```
        int[] Array = new int[] {7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 1};
```

2.) `Array.Length` won't return number of elements inside array. You need `Array.Count()`. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection) for more detail.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Count() / 2; i++)
        {
            Split1[i] = Array[i]; //This is where i get my error
        }
```