# How to find the column count of list of lists in C#?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, jagged-arrays, column-count

```
public static void matrix(List<List<int>> matrix)
{
    //matrix.Count is for amount of Row here
}
```

**Example**

Here the jagged array is

```
{{ 1,  2,  3},
 { 4,  5,  6},
 { 7,  8,  9},
 {10, 11, 12}}
```

Then `matrix.Count` gives `4`.

Here I want column count.

If this is *array* instead of *List* then I can use `matrix.GetLength(0)` and `matrix.GetLength(1)` to find Row count and Column count?

Comment: Try Using ToList()

Comment: It is not a [2D](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) list but rather a [jagged array](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) as it is [managed underlying](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/). Also this is not a (standard) [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) (as I know), whatever here the example looks like a 3x4 matrix. (special case). Thus talking about a column count or number or index is irrelevant, I think. It is more a level (nodes count) like in trees/graphs.

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/) • [Why we have both jagged array and multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Length Of Columns in Jagged Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049205/get-length-of-columns-in-jagged-array)

Comment: What do you expect from the example provided for `GetColumnCount (matrix)`? What about the sample from answers of @.MrMoeinM and @.DmitryBychenko?

Answer (score 1):

In *general* case, since you have *jagged* structure you can define *different* `ColCount`:

```
 {
  { 1, 2, 3  },  // Average Columns - 3
  { 4, 5, 6, 7}, // Max Columns - 4
  { 8, 9},       // Min Columns - 2
 }
```

Assuming that `null` list has `0` columns you can put:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 int minColCount = matrix.Min(list => list?.Count ?? 0); 
 int maxColCount = matrix.Max(list => list?.Count ?? 0);
 int avgColCount = (int)Math.Round(matrix.Average(list => list?.Count ?? 0));
```

If you can *guarantee* that `matrix` is *rectangular* and doesn't contain `null`, you can put

```
 int colCount = matrix.Count > 0 ? matrix[0].Count : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a list of list of int. In this situation, there is no guaranty that you have a matrix with fix column size.

For example `{ {1}, {4,5,6}, {7,8}, {10,11,12,13} }` is a possible combination.

But, if you are sure inside lists have the same size you can get the first list's size.

```
int column = matrix?.FirstOrDefault()?.Count ?? -1;
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at top of your code.