# Why Kotlin has .length for String and .size for collections?

Tags: kotlin

What is the logic behind this that `String` has `.length` but `Collections` has `.size`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason is to minimize confusion when migrating from Java, which has the same method names. In pre-1.0 versions of Kotlin, we tried to make the method names the same, bu this tripped people up constantly (because both of those methods are used extremely often).

Answer (score 1):

Well, those are just naming conventions, which are basically just a taste of the creator of the programming language.

A `String` tends to refer to contiguous elements, so we can say that a string has a `length`. Naming it `count` will be weird right?

When we have a collection, we usually iterate it or want to know the amount of items **inside** it. So, I want to know the size of that collection.

You can read a lot more here about naming conventions: [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection)