# Why does Array.length return a number greater than the actual highest array index? Doesn't javascript start counting from 0?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

The length property of an object which is an instance of type Array sets or returns the number of elements in that array. The value is an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(array.length);
```

Output = 3

Comment: I know, exactly. So ...

0 = 1,
1 = 2,
2 = 3
Why doesn't it give me 3??

Comment: your output should be 3? the index starts at 0 but the length is the total number of elements present.

Comment: For me its showing `3`

Comment: Let me double check.

Comment: Are you asking why a 3-element array has length 3?

Comment: Yes, why? It should be 2

Comment: The `length` of the array is the total number of elements in that array. What exactly is the confusion?

Comment: Why? By definition the length of an array is the number of elements. 0,1,2 is a list of 3 numbers.

Comment: So, I think the confusion is that JavaScript starts /counting/ at 1 ... 1 element = 1 ... but JavaScript stores data in the 0 index of an array.

Comment: I have three things, but you are saying it should be 2, because the index starts at zero and not 1?? That is a new argument I have not heard.

Comment: ahhh, I think I get it now. If I wanted to change the the third element I would have to refer to it this way array[2] = "poop". The length and the index are two different things. I see.

Comment: Actually let me give it another shot -- the index starts at 0, where the first element lives.  But JS does start counting at 0 when there is nothing present. `[].length === 0`

Comment: Just a guess -- you are a VBA programmer? In VBA there is no array length function, but there is a `UBound` function which is used in its place. `UBound(A) = 2` if `A = Array(0,1,2)`. If so, it is a natural mistake to expect that `length` would work like `UBound`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Comment: @JohnColeman haha, nope, I'm a CodeAcademy wannabe javascript programmer

Comment: Whether or not you are a VBA programmer, it isn't an unreasonable point of confusion for someone starting out in programming. I don't think that the downvotes are really warranted.

Comment: I didnt downvote but others may have because this question has been asked a lot. Here is one of the more upvoted answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/300540/2647442

Comment: @JohnColeman, oh the downvotes, they burn, but I need to understand this so ...let the downvotes come hehe

Comment: [This post](https://dev.to/adarshgoyal/why-array-index-in-c-starts-from-0-not-1-119h) at dev gives a reason why starting at 0 is preferable.

Answer (score 5):

The first element is at index 0. The length is the number of elements. Counting and indices are unrelated. If indices started at 99 but there were only four elements, the length would not be 103, it would be 4. Likewise of the first index was -66 and there were only 6 elements the list would not be -60 elements long.

I agree it can be confusing. Maybe think of indices as names*. So each place in an array has a name. For our convenience the names are related to the position in the array of each element.

The positions start counting from 0, but the number of elements starts counting from 1, as Marie says in her comment.

---

*In fact in javascript they are names, as all indices are also properties.

Comment: The first element is 0.
The second element is 1.
The third element is 2.
I should be getting 2, not 3.

Comment: Length and indexing are entirely separate concepts.The "Length" is the number of items in a collection, starting at one. The last index is `Length - 1`

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic - No. The array has 3 elements, hence it is showing 3. This is correct.
As Matt pointed out, the indices are a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

The OP original stated that the following code returned `4` when the actual value is `3`.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(array.length);
```

The problem is you're getting confused between the `.length` property which gives you the number of items in the array, and the index of the items.

Last index of the array is `2`, because the index starts at `0`... however, the length will remain as `3`

Comment: I didn't downvote. But yea, It's 3, but I still don't get it. I should be getting 2, because there are 3 elements in the array, and javascript starts counting from 0.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is "Why is length higher than the highest index?" and you are answering  the inverse. It also doesn't actually explain anything, just demonstrates what the OP already understands to be the functionality.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic `length` doesnot mean the last index. `length` means total elements in array.